# Twitter Service Connect with Constant ID

Tags: social-media

I am able to send Tweets with:

```
twitter = ServiceConnect["Twitter", "New"]
```

Then the command takes me to the API to authorize and then gives me an ID

[image]

How can I use a constant ID in the syntax? I try to use

`ID = "7AASA3sfsfw-44h-fr67-w45d- asassa787879sas"` ... whatever the ID Wolfram gives me (btw the one here is fake).

```
twitter = ServiceConnect["Twitter", ID]
```

But it doesn't work. Documentation is not clear about the ID. Any ideas on how a constant ID can be used?

Answer (score 1):

I could not try with Twitter because I don't have an account, so I tried with Dropbox.

I think you should extract the ID from the `ServiceObject` returned by `ServiceConnect`. Here is what I tried:

```
dropbox = ServiceConnect["Dropbox", "New"]
```

[image: connected]

The extract the connection ID from the `ServiceObject` itself:

```
dboxID = dropbox["ID"]
(* Out: "connection-f345cd78bda2ad8eb885477ec4b22487" *)
```

I then tried to close the connection, reopen it using the ID i saved, and checking the ID on this second object returned the same value as before:

```
ServiceDisconnect[dropbox]
```

Check that I am disconnected:

```
dropbox["ID"]
```

[image: disconnection confirmation]

Reconnect with the saved ID:

```
ServiceConnect["Dropbox", dboxID]

dboxID = dropbox["ID"]
```

The output returns the same connection ID.

Comment: Thanks! adding the `connection-` part to the ID fixed the issue.

Comment: @fonsi Glad it helped!